# Form1.Hide() how to get this object back to Active/.Show() ? when running Form2 is active

Tags: c#, winforms, show-hide

form1 & form2  there are 2 forms.

```
Form1.hide();
Form2 x=new Form2();
x.Show();
```

when form2 is shown, & after closing form2 i want the same object form1 back ... how to do it?
Note: i don't want to create new object of form1.

Please share your comments.

Comment: Submit to x.FormClosed event and show Form1 in this event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Form1

```
    private void Form1_button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        this.Hide(); // this will hide current form
        frm.Show(this);

    }
```

In Form2

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner != null) 
        {
            this.Owner.Show();
            this.Owner.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer, But Problem is i want to call dynamically from Form2 ( not within form1 ) 
[ in the form2 closing event itself ]
How to do that...?